# which AIR SDK versions will run which iOS versions

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.7

Where can I find information about which AIR SDKs can target each version of iOS.

Specifically, we are updating our app from AIR SDK 3.4 to the current 3.7; however, we aren't sure which versions of iOS the new SDK will work with.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a better question to ask Adobe.  Best I could find is here: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/faq.html that AIR 3.5 supports iOS 6.  When creating native extensions or exporting a release build you can specify the iOS SDK.

Comment: @flextras: Thanks for the prompt reply! I will try putting the question to the Flex forum in the Adobe Community.  Regarding the "Apple iOS SDK" field in the Native Extensions tab of the Export Release Build wizard, my sense is that that only applies to native extensions.  Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: My memory is that there is another place to specify the Apple iOS SDK.  One spot was "Mac only"; but another spot allowed the SDK to be specified on Windows too.  Of course, I couldn't find that second spot, so my memory could be wrong.